# With a generic repository for entity framework, how do I query entities which implement a specific interface?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I am using the Repository pattern with Entity Framework and have implemented a generic repository.

For certain types of entities though, I do not want to remove the record from the database, instead if want to set the `IsDeleted` bool to true.

To this effect, I have create this simple interface:

**IEntityProtectedDelete.cs**

```
public interface IEntityProtectedDelete
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Is is implemented on my entity like this:

**Queue.cs**

```
public class Queue : IEntityProtectedDelete
{
    public Queue() 
    {
        IsDeleted = false;
    }

    [Key]
    public int QueueId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Below is a portion of the generic repository I am using.  The `Delete` method works as expected, and set the `IsDelete` property to true when the above Interface is used.

However, I can't quite figure out how to correctly query the database if the entity implements `IEntityProtectedDelete`.

**GenericRepository.cs**

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DBContext context;
protected IDBSet dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(IContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        if (entity is IEntityProtectedDelete)
        {
            (entity as IEntityProtectedDelete).IsDeleted = true;
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else { dbSet.Remove(entity); }  
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        if (typeof(IEntityProtectedDelete).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            return context.Set<T>().OfType<IEntityProtectedDelete>().Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false).ToList() as IEnumerable<T>;
        }
        else { return context.Set<T>().ToList(); }
    }
}
```

In the GetAll() method, the `OfType<>` throws the exception:

```
'IEntityProtectedDelete' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types."
```

If this isn't going to work, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

Soft Delete pattern for Entity Framework has been discussed on SO and the accepted solution is described here

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/10/soft-delete-pattern-for-entity.html

The trick is to define your `IsDeleted` as a **discriminator column** so that EF automatically appends filtering subqueries.

Comment: "Soft Delete", the name I was looking for. Thanks for the information, it is certainly very helpful. One limitation with this approach appears to be that EF will exclude these records on all queries due to the discriminator.  I need to be able to include these records in a "GetById()" scenario, and some other cases for reporting. Additionally, I may need a Purge function that actually deletes the record.

Comment: @dlux: This is easily achieved with **two** context classes. The base class includes the discriminator normally. The subclass defines soft deleting. With a factory you switch between the two. Becuase of the direct inheritance, you don't define your model twice.